# Changing page permissions at runtime under a debugger

Tags: debuggers, x64dbg

Does x64dbg or another debugger provide a way to change the page permissions for all mapped pages for a given section at runtime? Perhaps via a plugin?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in IDA by calling `VirtualProtect` in the process' context with Appcall. From
[Practical Appcall examples](https://www.hex-rays.com/blog/practical-appcall-examples/):

> In the following example we will change the PE header page protection
> to execute/read/write (normally it is read-only):
>
> ```
> virtprot = Appcall.proto("kernel32_VirtualProtect",
>   "BOOL __stdcall VirtualProtect(LPVOID addr, DWORD sz, DWORD newprot, PDWORD oldprot);")
> r = virtprot(0x400000, 0x1000, Appcall.Consts.PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, Appcall.byref(0));
> print "VirtualProtect returned:", r
> RefreshDebuggerMemory()
> ```

Possibly other debuggers can do something similar (e.g. [WinDbg has `.call`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-call--call-function-))

Answer (score 0):

From the x64dbg Memory Map tab you can right click a mapped section and select Set Page Memory Rights from the context menu.

[image: Section Memory Context Menu]

From there, you can control the access for each page in that section.

[image: Page Permissions]

Igor's answer offers a lot of flexibility though, and Im not sure if x64dbg provides an API for this in their plugin/scripting interface.